# Handle spaces in HTML5 list in Flask template

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the following template code for a searchable form, where it shows the suggestions in a drop down list:

```
<input list="all_label_names" name="label_list" type="search" required>
<datalist id="all_label_names">
{% for label in label_names %}
    <option value={{label}}>
{% endfor %}
</datalist>
```

However when the `label` contains a space, only the first part before the space gets appended to the list items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes around the `value` attribute.

```
<option value="{{label}}">
```

should work.

```
<input list="all_label_names" name="label_list" type="search" required>
<datalist id="all_label_names">
{% for label in label_names %}
    <option value="{{label}}">
{% endfor %}
</datalist>
```

The problem is, if `label` is `a b`, it would evaluate to

```
    <option value=a b>
```

which is obviously evaluated as `value=a` and `b` is treated as the next attribute (invalid ofcourse). Hence the issue.